# Rename a uploaded file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use the [SitePoint Drag and Drop file upload](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/) to upload images to my site.  My cshtml page contains the form and the userID for the current user.  I would like to rename the file to the userID, but AJAX asynchronously uploads the image without sending the userID data along.  Therefore I can't rename the file.  How can I pass the userID from the cshtml page to the php page, via JS/AJAX, to be able to rename the file?

Here is the cshtml:

```
 <form id="upload" action="test2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
                
                    <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" accept="image" />
                    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="@userID" hidden /> //This is referencing a SQL query to get the UserID
//It's the data I want to pass along
                    
                    <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
               
 <script src="filedrag.js"></script>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] :    false);
$userID = ???

if ($fn) {
$file_ext = substr($fn, strripos($fn, '.'));
$newfilename = $userID.$file_ext;
// AJAX call
file_put_contents(
    'uploads/' . $newfilename,
    file_get_contents('php://input')
);
echo "$fn uploaded";
exit();
```

Here is the full JS:

```
(function() {

// getElementById
function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
// output information
function Output(msg) {
    var m = $id("messages");
    m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
}
// file drag hover
function FileDragHover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
}
// file selection
function FileSelectHandler(e) {

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
        UploadFile(f);
    }
}
// output file information
function ParseFile(file) {

    Output(
        "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
        "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
        "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
        "</strong> bytes</p>"
    );

    // display an image
    if (file.type.indexOf("image") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            Output(
                "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong><br />" +
                '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" /></p>'
            );
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    // display text
    if (file.type.indexOf("text") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            Output(
                "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong></p><pre>" +
                e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") +
                "</pre>"
            );
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}
// upload JPEG files
function UploadFile(file) {

    // following line is not necessary: prevents running on SitePoint servers
    if (location.host.indexOf("sitepointstatic") >= 0) return

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload && file.type == "image/jpeg" && file.size <= $id("MAX_FILE_SIZE").value) {

        // create progress bar
        var o = $id("progress");
        var progress = o.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
        progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode("upload " + file.name));

        // progress bar
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
            progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
        }, false);

        // file received/failed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
            }
        };

        // start upload
        xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
        xhr.send(file);
    }
}
// initialize
function Init() {

    var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
        filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
        submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

    // file select
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

    // is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {

        // file drop
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
        filedrag.style.display = "block";
    }
}
// call initialization file
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
}
})();
```

Comment: Your code has multiple sintaxis errors. Try to fix it first. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the main parts from the PHP and CSHTML to save space.  I'm really only focused on trying to pass the userID in the CSHTML to the PHP via the JS/AJAX.  I assume I need to add some sort of variable in the JS relating to the "id" cshtml input?

Comment: That's a bad idea since anybody can spoof a user ID then. Surely there is server-side authentication and you can get the user ID from that layer?

Comment: @Jeff - I'm currently pulling in the userID from SQL using razor and then referencing the variable in the hiddin input field, all in the cshtml.  I'm not sure if this is the best way, just what I could come up with.  Do you know how to do it from the server? In PHP, do you know how I could get the username from the user logged in (the one uploading the file)?  I tried get_current_user but that didn't give me the login name/userid.

Comment: Hmm, there should be something stored in `$_SESSION` that contains the user ID or a way to get it. Try `var_dump()`ing `$_SESSION` and poke around in there (as a logged-in user).